# How to launch a editor with better_errors in WSL environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubymine

I'm using `better_errors` gem in WSL environments.

When I used Mac, I could open a file by clicking error page's file path like below.
[image]

I have this line in `config/environments/development.rb`.

```
BetterErrors.editor='x-mine://open?file=%{file}&line=%{line}' if defined?(BetterErrors)
```

The link URL seems properly created.

```
x-mine://open?file=%2Fhome%2Fironsand%2Fdev%2Fmyapp%2Fapp%2Fcontrollers%2Fcompanies_controller.rb&line=12`
```

How can I open a URL start with `x-mine:` in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

From Microsoft documentation itself, you have to hack your way through the system registry.

You need to set it up like the following:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   x-mine
      (Default) = "URL:RubyMine Protocol"
      URL Protocol = ""
      shell
         open
            command
               (Default) = "C:\Program Files\IntelliJ\mine.exe" "%1"
```

(you might have to change your path for it to point to the actual path of where you have installed RubyMine).

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer `x-mine` is recognized as URL Protocol and I could open the URL by "c:\Program Files\JetBrains\RubyMine 2021.2\bin\rubymine64.exe", but it seems I also need to replace `/` to `\`. I'll check if it's possible to configure the file path.